# PHP variables in WHERE clause, how to?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, where-clause

I have following PHP script. I want to count and print comments for each article.

The id for each article can be "recalled" by this: `<?php echo $listing['Listing']['listing_id'];?>` (this return the contentid number)

Now, I have this script:

```
<?php
          $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
          $query = "SELECT COUNT(comments) AS totalcount WHERE contentid = ????? ";
          $db->setQuery($query);
          $count = $db->loadResult();
echo ($count); ?>
```

I tried to add in WHERE clause this:

```
"... WHERE contentid = {$listing['Listing']['listing_id']}"
```

but $count returns "0" zero.
How can I add this variable in the WHERE clause?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you confirm that the query actually succeeded? Have you output the query string you generated and tried running it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of an integer:

```
$query = "SELECT
    COUNT(comments) AS totalcount
WHERE
    contentid = " . ((int) $listing['Listing']['listing_id']);
```

In the case of a string:

```
$query = "SELECT
    COUNT(comments) AS totalcount
WHERE
    contentid = " . mysql_real_escape_string($listing['Listing']['listing_id']);
```

The biggest thing to be weary of is SQL injection. This makes your queries safe. The explicit cast to `int` will ensure an int value is passed, even if the value is erroneous, at least you wont be open to any attack.

Comment: @Frist van Campen Simply PERFECT! You rock! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use sprintf and escape the string.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(comments) AS totalcount WHERE contentid = '%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($listing['Listing']['listing_id']));
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(comments) AS totalcount WHERE contentid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['Listing']['listing_id'])."'";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(comments) AS totalcount WHERE contentid = ".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['Listing']['listing_id']);
```

depending on the data type.

Comment: Quoting the string... agreed.

Comment: Yes, I suggest mysql_real_escape_string($foo) on variables to prevent injection.

Comment: Do not use this. appending user-supplied variables is terrible practice.

Comment: I don't imagine that an ID would be user supplied, but if it is wrap it with mysql_real_escape_string()